# Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am trying to set up a connection in Pentaho 5.3.0.0-213 to mysql on localhost. I am using a Mac running OS 10.10.2. I can connect to the DB using Sequel Pro and have read through all the answers already given on this site (and others!) and have downloaded and copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar to data-integration/lib and still get the same error.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

The whole error message is as follows:
Error connecting to database [localhost_con] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:417)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:357)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:310)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:300)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2685)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:318)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:59)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.editConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:87)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3096)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:3031)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.access$2400(Spoon.java:347)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$27.widgetDefaultSelected(Spoon.java:6121)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1316)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7979)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9310)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:654)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:116)
    at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
    at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.launch(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:561)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:400)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:543)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
    ... 76 more
```

Hostname       : localhost
Port           : 3306
Database name  : my_learning_sql

Comment: can you attach the pentaho.log and catalina.out logs?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem depending on the version of the database and the version of the MySQL driver. I was using mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar and had to upgrade to mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar in order to get mine to work. Perhaps yours is the opposite problem and you could downgrade your driver to mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar to fix yours?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it, but no change.

Comment: It works when I click `TEST CONNECTION`. But it gives the exception when the job is running. Tried upgrade/downgrading the driver. No luck

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue (same versions you've listed above for drivers, OS, etc.), and ended up tracking it down to this:  my `~/.kettle/kettle.properties` file didn't list the DB Host setting the same way the database connection in the transform listed it.

```
deweygarwood$ cat ~/.kettle/kettle.properties 
# This file was generated by Pentaho Data Integration version 5.1.2.1.
... stuff here

DW_HOST=localhost <~~~ this line
DW_DBPORT=3306
DW_DBNAME=datawarehouse
DW_DBUSER=root
DW_DBPASSWORD=
```

didn't match the name listed in my Database Connection inside the kettle transform, which was `${DW_DBHOST}`

The way I discovered this was using the "Test" button on the database connection screen and scrolling to the bottom.  The output showed the variable "${DW_DBHOST}" rather than "localhost".  Updating my `~/.kettle/kettle.properties` file to use the same variable name resolved the issue.

Assuming you're using the kettle.properties for your connection settings, I'd expect a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. download Mysql connector from here: [connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=489461)
2. unzip the file
3. copy only the two *.jar files into data-integration/lib/
4. restart Pentaho
5. go to: Database Connection -> choose MySql -> edit your connection info -> test connection.

These steps resolved my issue.